# PHP - destroy session and remove cookies

Tags: php, session, cookies

I have a problem clear cookie when session is destroyed or expired. I create application with session (logged user) and cookies (cart) and I must clear cart when session is destroyed or expired. I'm tring use $_SESSION[SESSION_NAME], but not always $_SESSION[SESSION_NAME] has been removed after destroy or expire.

```
if(!isset($_COOKIE[SESSION_NAME])) {
   clearCookie();
}
```

When I remove cookie with session ID then cookies has been cleared, but when session expire then cookie (and cookie with session ID) have been existed.

I'm tried all session functions (https://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.session.php), but I'm not found good solution.
How to clear cookie when session has been removed or expired?

Answer (score 0):

As your **cookie** is identified by data from your **session**, it would be logical to delete/clear the cookie before destroying the session.

So, whenever you need to destroy the session, first clear the cookie, then destroy your session.

Something like this:

```
clearCookie();
unset($_SESSION);
session_destroy();
```

Answer (score 0):

set cookie value to the past date

```
setcookie($cookie_name, '', time() - (86400 * 30), "/","");  // 86400 = 1 day
session_destroy();
```